# How to create SKSprite node one by one in For loop using Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to create 10 SKSPrite nodes via a For loop. I want the nodes to appear one by one but with my code, all 10 nodes appear at the same time. Increasing the wait duration does not help. Thank you in advance.

```
for i in 1 ... 10 {

    self.stone[i - 1].position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: -100)
    self.stone[i - 1].anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.stone[i - 1].size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    self.stone[i - 1].physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    self.stone[i - 1].physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    self.stone[i - 1].physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Object1
    self.stone[i - 1].zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(self.stone[i - 1])   

    let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: 0.3)
    let actionRolling = SKAction.animate(with: stone[i - 1].arrayTexture, timePerFrame: 0.05)
    let actionDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
    let actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([actionMove,actionRolling,actionDelay])
    stone[i - 1].run(actionSequence)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all your doing in your code is making a loop that creates the nodes, any duration that you apply to those nodes in that loop will affect them all equally. You need an variable outside of the loop that gets incremented in the loop per instance of node.

```
var delay: Double = 1.0 

for i in 1 ... 10 {

    self.run(.wait(forDuration: delay) {

        self.stone[i - 1].position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: -100)
        self.stone[i - 1].anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.stone[i - 1].size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        self.stone[i - 1].physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
        self.stone[i - 1].physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        self.stone[i - 1].physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Object1
        self.stone[i - 1].zPosition = 2
        self.addChild(self.stone[i - 1])   

        let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: 0.3)
        let actionRolling = SKAction.animate(with: stone[i - 1].arrayTexture, timePerFrame: 0.05)
        let actionDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
        let actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([actionMove,actionRolling,actionDelay])
        stone[i - 1].run(actionSequence)
    }

    delay += 1.0
}
```

Comment: Hi
Your solutions works. thank you.
However, I have no idea how and why it works!
I don't understand 2 points here:
1) What does "self.run(.wait(forDuration: delay) {" do ?
How does it do?
And did not know you add the curly brackets {} after the run function.
2) delay +=1
Why must the delay increase per iteration? Does it mean between the 9 and 10 iteration, the delay is 10? It does not seem like in when I run program.

Where can I read more about this? Thank you again.

Comment: The {} at the end is the same as typing run(action: SKAction, completion: () -> Void). It just means after the action is run execute this {} block of code

Comment: as for the time delay...imagine that in your loop is just the statement print(1 + 1) and it goes through the loop 4 times. You will see 2 get printed to the console 4 times not 2, 4, 6, 8. It is no different than your actionDelay you are not adding it to anything, so you actually get 10 actionDelay's with a time of 1.0 and the phone is able to process all ten of those statements almost instantaneously making it seem like they are all occurring. You are correct by the 10th iteration the delay is 10

Comment: I understand now that the run(action: SKAction) {} is the same as run(action: SKAction, completion: () -> Void). The code within the {} is the completion handler code. Thanks.

Comment: For the delay +=1.0, I still do not fully understand. The delay is 1 for iteration 1 and the delay becomes 2 in iteration 2 and at iteration 10, the delay is 10. So, the total delays for all the iteration is 1+2+3+..+10. This means the delay gets successively longer per iteration. However, when I run the program, then delay per iteration seem pretty much the same (which is exactly what I want). Please help a newbie understand this. thank you.

Comment: it is a little confusing at first. the delay for iteration 1 is 1 sec, 2 seconds for iteration 2...10 seconds for iteration 10. Now imagine that all ten items are getting created at once (which they essentially are because processing of the code DOESN'T wait for the iteration). so, all 10 items are processed at once but we are just setting the delay until they get added to the scene and displayed.